# Import threejs code in Aframe inside a component

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to create a-frame component using threejs code. How to integrate threejs module in the a-frame component? Please guide me about this, I am struggling to find a solution of this.
I am trying to integrate this in my component

```
<script type="module">
    AFRAME.registerComponent('navigation-controls', {
    init: function(){
        let el = this.el;
        import * as THREE from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.module.js'
        import { IndoorControls } from 'https://raw.githack.com/wobushijiujiu/three.js/dev/examples/jsm/controls/IndoorControls.js';
        // tried this using outside of the component if was not working there also
       let scene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
        let camera = scene.camera;
        let renderer = scene.renderer;
        let groundControls = new IndoorControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
       console.log(groundControls); //this is showing error - IndoorControls not found
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame includes Three.js natively, so the THREE object is globally available without having to include anything else.

Comment: Yes. I understand that but I want to include this from 'https://raw.githack.com/wobushijiujiu/three.js/dev/examples/jsm/controls/IndoorControls.js library inside the component.